# C# - Replacing characters in a string

Tags: c#, string, connection-string

I have a string that contains a login, database, and a password.

```
string str = "user Id=abc, database=DDD, Password=mypasswd"
```

I want to be able to replace the database value "DDD" with a different value.

I tried using the string.Replace, but I won't know what the existing database will be.

Does anyone know of a simple solution?

Comment: Split the string at commas. Split each resulting string at equal signs. Replace the second value where the first value is "database". Join back.

Comment: Is it just for connection string? In that case you can use ConnectionStringBuilder , which parses and initializes different properties, and you can easily change database property and get back new string with new value.

Comment: I'm not to familiar with the ConnectionStringBuilder. I'll look into it. Thank you.

Comment: @hmakled, I have added the answer and I also posted link to MSDN which says that this is the the only safe way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One alternative is to use a Regex, this would do the replace for you:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string cStr = "user Id=abc, database=DDD, Password=mypasswd";
Console.WriteLine(cStr);

Regex r = new Regex("(?<=database=)(.+?)(?=,)");
cStr = r.Replace(cStr, "NewDatabaseName");

Console.WriteLine(cStr);
```

**NOTE:** this was compiled, run, and proven with `scriptcs` so it's fairly droppable into your solution.

Comment: what class does Regex use? I can't seem to access it.

Comment: @hmakled, the class name in `Regex`, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx

Comment: @hmakled, add a `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` at the top of your `.cs` file.

Comment: Ok did that and it shows now, but where is my string in the example you showed?

Comment: @hmakled, in the example you showed you used a variable named `str`, note that I'm reassigning `str` *and* using it in the `Replace` method call.

Comment: yes sorry. Ok i tried it like you show but its not changing it. I printed the string before and after and still shows same database.

Comment: Michael, your example works but its removing the "database=" and replacing it with the database name. It should leave the "database=" and add the database value to it like "database=AAA". Can you see whats wrong? thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28840/discussion-between-hmakled-and-michael-perrenoud)

Answer (score 11):

**Following is the only recommended way by MSDN to prevent Connection String Injection Attacks**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254947.aspx

```
// cs stores previous connection string which came from config

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = 
    new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cs);
builder.InitialCatalog = "NEWDB";

// you get your database name replaced properly...
cs = builder.ToString();
```

Based on the type of database or database driver, you have to use different class, for MySql it should be MySqlConnectionStringBuilder and name of property might be Database.

Comment: This is the whole reason ConnectionStringBuilder was created.

Comment: Yeah, and one other nice thing is that it's capable of splitting up more complex connection strings that contain uncommon attributes as well.

Comment: I can't access/find SqlConnectionStringBuilder am I missing a class for it?

Comment: Include namespace System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: @AkashKava I added the namespace but still can't access SqlConnectionStringBuilder??

Comment: @hmakled, are you referencing `System.Data.SqlClient` as an assembly also? If I'm not mistaken that is now a separate assembly.

Comment: You have to add reference to System.Data.dll to your project or app, are you connecting to SQL Server or compact or any other database?

Comment: @Akash still can't get the SqlConnectionStringBuilder to show??? I added all the namespaces. I don't see where I can add the System.Data.dll? I clicked on references and did "add reference" but couldn't find System.Data.dll

Comment: What is the version of .Net?

Comment: I believe the version is 2.0

Answer (score 4):

How about using [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)?

```
string username = "abc";
string database = "myDB";
string password = "my_pw";

string str = String.Format("user Id={0}, database={1}, Password={2}",
                           username, database, password);
```

You could then load these values (or even the whole connection string) from a configuration file.

Comment: the string is already existing and its longer than i displayed. I'm not creating the string i'm pulling it from a configuration file.

Comment: Ah, yea that makes a big difference. Unless you don't have an appropriate answer already, I'll put one together once I get home.

Comment: @eandersson, I did it before you get home :)

Answer (score 2):

Regexes are also an option:

```
string str = "user Id=abc, database=DDD, Password=mypasswd",
    newDatabase = "newDb";

Console.WriteLine( Regex.Replace( str, @"(?<=database=)(.*?)(?=,)", m => newDatabase ) );
```

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud yes, I was surprised no one posted it. So +1 to you as well for solidarity :D

Comment: @BlackBear - tried your way but its not replacing the value. stays the same

Comment: @hmakled regex.replace returns the new string and leaves the input one untouched

Answer (score 1):

Split the string at the comma separator, then take the second index of the resulting array, split at the equal separator, substitute the second element, then recombine all

```
string str = "user Id=abc, database=DDD, Password=mypasswd";
string[] parts = str.Split(',');
string[] dbparts = parts[1].Split('=');
dbparts[1] = "new_database_name";

parts[1] = string.Join("=", dbparts);
string final = string.Join(", ", parts);
```

and, well, with a bit of error checking would be safer.

Answer (score 0):

Same as above but if you are fun of LINQ

```
string str = "user Id=abc, database=DDD, Password=mypasswd";

var q = from part in str.Split(new[] {','})
                let trimedPart= part.Trim()
                let replacedPart  =trimedPart.StartsWith("database=")?trimedPart.Replace("DDD","newValue"):trimedPart
                select replacedPart;

        var newConStr = q.Aggregate((current, next) => current + "," + next);
```

Answer (score 0):

These solutions are all great, but doesn't one long and confusing line have a certain elegance?

```
"user Id=abc, database=DDD, Password=mypasswd".Substring(0, "user Id=abc, database=DDD, Password=mypasswd".IndexOf("database=")) + "database=" + "[YOUR VALUE HERE]" + ", " + "user Id=abc, database=DDD, Password=mypasswd".Substring("user Id=abc, database=DDD, Password=mypasswd".IndexOf("Password="))
```

Output: `user Id=abc, database=[YOUR VALUE HERE], Password=mypasswd`